# Format Number with Leading Zeros, Hyphen and Limit

Tags: php, regex, printf

I'd like to format given string with following rules;

- Get only digits out of it
- Get them in 4 digit groups
- Each group must lead with 0's
- There must be 3 groups.

Given : `1234` Expected Result: `0000-0000-1234`

Given : `123` Expected Result: `0000-0000-0123`

Given : `12345` Expected Result: `0000-0001-2345`

Given : `123456789012345` Expected Result: `1234-5678-9012`

Is there anyway to achieve this without getting into creating a method / function for it? Such as with regex and / or using `sprintf`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess it was clear. I did it with a method as I couldn't find a right way to do it with a single liner.
It would be nice to hear why it gets negative votes. Seems like this community is going down the hill as this is not a way to encourage people ask questions.

Comment: @Revenant Though not my downvote, SO helps the people with getting through the answer provided they have tried something. One can't do others home work but can help achieving it if struggle arises

Comment: @Revenant, I guess you got downvoted because a good question caontains the code with which you are tried to get you expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php), a much simpler approach

```
<?php
$no_arr = ['1234', '123', '12345', '123456789012345'];

foreach($no_arr as $n){
    echo vsprintf("%04d-%04d-%04d",str_split(sprintf("%012d", $n), 4))."<br/>";
}
```

Output will be:

```
0000-0000-1234
0000-0000-0123
0000-0001-2345
1234-5678-9012
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking for an elegant single liner and it seems that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `str_pad()` to format the strings with all zeros, and `chunk_split()` to add a `-` for every 4 characters, `substr()` is responsable for limit the lenght of string at 14 characters, in the last example the string have 16 characters, `substr()` fix this.

```
$arr = ['1234', '123', '12345', '123456789012345'];

foreach($arr as $item){
   $str = str_pad($item, 12, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
   echo   substr(chunk_split($str, 4, '-'), 0, 14) .'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
0000-0000-1234
0000-0000-0123
0000-0001-2345
1234-5678-9012
```

Comment: thanks. I've been using it a bit longer way. Yours is a single liner and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Just format the string using sprintf, split it and then implode!

```
<?php
$no_arr = ['1234', '123', '12345', '123456789012345'];

foreach($no_arr as $n){
    $formatted_number = str_split(sprintf("%012d", $n), 4);
    echo substr(implode("-", $formatted_number), 0, 14) .'<br>';
}
```

Output will be:

```
0000-0000-1234
0000-0000-0123
0000-0001-2345
1234-5678-9012
```

Explanation:

```
$twelve_digit = sprintf("%012d", $n);
$split_into_4 = str_split($twelve_digit, 4);
$add_hyphen = implode("-", $split_into_4);
$remove_trailing_chars = substr($add_hyphen, 0, 14);
echo $remove_trailing_chars ." <br/>";
```

One Liner:

```
echo substr(implode("-", str_split(sprintf("%012d", $n), 4)), 0, 14);
```